# Null Pointer Exception in Recycler View Holder onClick

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I have a RecyclerHolder called EventHolder which I use in multiple layouts. It works perfectly in one activity.
In the second activity, while the RecyclerView displays everything correctly, it throws a null pointer exception when I click on one of the items in the list in an attempt to move to the 'ViewSingleEvent' activity. I cannot figure out why this is, especially since it works for the first layout.

Code from EventHolder class:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //handle the on click event for the ViewHolder - get single event details and switch activity
        if (this.event != null) {
            //getting the ID of the particular event clicked
            String indEventId = this.event.id;
            //using an intent to pass data between values
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewSingleEvent.class); //nullpointerexception here
            i.putExtra("id",indEventId);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

The line `Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewSingleEvent.class);` holds the error. Is this something to do with getting the context of the second activity? Please help.

**ALSO:** I have already looked at multiple similar NullPointerException questions already, and have not found the answer to my question, so please don't mark this question as a duplicate - I'm stumped.

**Edit:** Code from EventHolder class where I get the context.

```
private Context context;

    public EventHolder(final Context context, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.context = context;
```

I THINK this is how I pass the context from the first activity (the one that works):

```
        //declaring the layout manager
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        eventsListview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This is what I did for the one that doesn't work. Note that it is a fragment, not an activity.

```
        //declaring the layout manager
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        eventsListview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: how do you get your context for your adapter in your first and second activity?

Comment: how are you passing `context` to this method

Comment: Edited question to include where I declare context in EventHolder class

Comment: @minikate, use this `v.getContext()` instead of `context` and show the Log stack trace

Comment: Do you mean this? ```this.context = itemView.getContext();```

Comment: @minikate, yes you can use like this. Where is your `adapter` and from where you are calling that `adapter` also show your Log stack where exactly you are getting that exception

Comment: That one change actually worked! I'm not sure how, but thank you :)

Comment: @minikate, It was the issue with `context` as a reference to your `Activity` or `fragment`. On that case, `Context` of `View` will could be never come up with that type of exception. Happy to help you. :)